# How to display/output/manipulate the contents of Dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I need to display the `List` of a `Dictionary` based on the `int key` I've entered in the console and `throw` an error message if it out of the given bounds of inputs in the console as well.

```
public class Channel
{
    const string displayChannel = "{0},{1},{2}";

    private Dictionary <int, string> ChannelLookup = 
    new Dictionary <int, string> ()
    {
        {1, new List<string>{"[A]","[B]","[C]"}},
        {2, new List<string>{"[A]"}
    };

    public string channelDisplay (int val)
    {
        if (!ChannelLookup.ContainsKey(val))
        {
            // throw exception
        }
        else
        {
            string display = string.Format(displayChannel, ChannelLookup[val]);
            return display;
        }
    }
}
```

> System.Format.Exception:'Index(zerobased) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Is it permitted to use LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: Sometimes I use `Aggregate` instead of `Join`, since it gives you more control.

```
var values = ChannelLookup[val].Values;
var display = values.Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}");
```

To use the Linq function `Aggregate`, you need to add `System.Linq` to your using directives.

Comment: Side note: The downside of `Aggregate` is  that it creates many `string` instances (an instance per item in `values`); if `values` is *long* `values.Aggregate` can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to display *arbitrary number* of items (say, `3` - `"[A]", "[B]", "[C]"` or just `1` - "A"); let's `Join` them instead of using `Format`

```
public class Channel {
  private Dictionary <int, List<string>> ChannelLookup = 
    new Dictionary <int, List<string>> () {
      {1, new List<string>() {"[A]", "[B]", "[C]"} },
      {2, new List<string>() {"[A]"} },
    };

  public string channelDisplay (int key) {
    if (ChannelLookup.TryGetValue(key, out var items))
      return string.Join(",", items);
    else 
      throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(key)} = {key} not found", nameof(key));
  }
}
```

Or even

```
public string channelDisplay(int key) => ChannelLookup.TryGetValue(key, out var items)
  ? string.Join(",", items)
  : throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(key)} = {key} not found", nameof(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET doesn't let you have unused format parameters, i.e. you can't do this
`string.Format("{0},{1}", "first value")` without also providing a value for {1}.

Your best bet here is probably string.Join. string.Join will concatenate the values you provide to it, placing the specified delimiter between each value.

[See the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__)

```
public class Channel
{
 private Dictionary <int, string> ChannelLookup = 
 new Dictionary <int, string> ()
 {
  {1, new List<string>{"[A]","[B]","[C]"}},
  {2, new List<string>{"[A]"}
 };

 public string channelDisplay (int val)
 {
  if(!ChannelLookup.ContainsKey(val))
  {
    // throw exception
  }
  else
  {
    string display = string.Join(",", ChannelLookup[val]);
    return display;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the format string `displayChannel` when using string.Join. `string.Join(",", ChannelLookup[val])` would be correct.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.